# WHMCS if Product ID in Cart

Tags: php, whmcs

I am currently looking for a method to append images and links to the cart / checkout page based on a certain product id in WHMCS, however I could not find a solution or Template Syntax to have this working. Does anyone have an idea on how to have this working?

Some expert advise would be really appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check templates/orderforms/web20cart/viewcart.tpl: after the line `{foreach key=num item=product from=$products}` add `{$product|@debug_print_var}` which will show you the $product variable, and there is the pid index (product id) as you requested.

Simply within the foreach you can use:

```
{if $product.pid == '123'} show custom image {/if}
```